# Unable to use jsonpath function for output parameter in Argo Workflows

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argoproj

I've one workflow in which I'm using `jsonpath` function for a output parameter to extract a specific value from json string, but it is failing with this error `Error (exit code 255)`

Here is my workflow

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: wf-dev-
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main

      dag:
        tasks:
          - name: dev-create
            templateRef:
              name: dev-create-wft
              template: main
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: param1
                  value: "val1"

          - name: dev-outputs
            depends: dev-create.Succeeded
            templateRef:
              name: dev-outputs-wft
              template: main
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: devoutputs
                  value: "{{=jsonpath(tasks.dev-create.outputs.parameters.devoutputs, '$.alias.value')}}"
```

In the above workflow task `dev-create` invokes another workflowTemplate `dev-create-wft` which returns the output of another workflowTemplate

Here is my workflowTemplate

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: dev-create-wft

spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      outputs:
        parameters:
          - name: devoutputs
            valueFrom:
               expression: "tasks['dev1'].outputs.parameters.devoutputs"
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: param1
      dag:
        tasks:
          - name: dev1
            templateRef:
              name: fnl-dev
              template: main
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: param1
                  value: "{{inputs.parameters.param1}}"
```

The returned json output looks like this

```
{
    "alias": {
        "value": "testing:dev1infra",
        "type": "string",
        "sensitive": false
    },
    "match": {
        "value": "dev1infra-testing",
        "type": "string",
        "sensitive": false
    }
}
```

Does `jsonpath` function supported in workflow? The reason why am asking is, it's working when I used the same function in another workflowTemplate `dev-outputs-wft`

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When an expression fails to evaluate, Argo Workflows simply does not substitute the expression with its evaluated value. Argo Workflows passes the expression *as if it were the parameter*.

`{{=}}` "expression tag templates" in Argo Workflows must be written according to the [expr language spec](https://github.com/antonmedv/expr/blob/master/docs/Language-Definition.md).

In simple tag templates, Argo Workflows itself does the interpreting. So hyphens in parameter names are allowed. For example, `value: "{{inputs.parameters.what-it-is}}"` is evaluated by Argo Workflows to be `value: "over 9000!"`.

But in expression tag templates, expr interprets hyphens as minus operators. So `value: "{{=inputs.parameters.what-it-is}}"` looks like a really weird mathematical expression, fails, and isn't substituted. The workaround is to use `['what-it-is']` to access the appropriate map item.

My guess is that your expression is failing, Argo Workflows is passing the expression to `dev-outputs-wft` un-replaced, and whatever shell script is receiving that parameter is breaking.

If I'm right, the fix is easy:

```
           - name: dev-outputs
             depends: dev-create.Succeeded
             templateRef:
               name: dev-outputs-wft
               template: main
             arguments:
               parameters:
                 - name: devoutputs
-                   value: "{{=jsonpath(tasks.dev-create.outputs.parameters.devoutputs, '$.alias.value')}}"
+                   value: "{{=jsonpath(tasks['dev-create'].outputs.parameters.devoutputs, '$.alias.value')}}"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works perfectly. I spent two days to figure out the solution but I didn't find the solution. Finally the solution provided by you working flawlessly.