# Conditional expression in withParam of argo workflow template spec

Tags: argo-workflows

Is it possible to specify a conditional expression in the `withParam` of a template step? For example, I have a very typical parallelization case that works fine:

```
#...
templates:
- name: my-template
  steps:
  - - name: make-list
      template: makes-a-list
  - - name: consume-list
      template: process-list-element
      arguments:
        parameters:
        - name: param-name
          value: "{{item}}"
      withParam: "{{steps.make-list.outputs.result}}"
```

What I'd like to do is be able to have `consume-list` use a different list of "items" to process in parallel, if specified. I've tried several variations of this:

```
withParam: "{{= workflow.parameters.use-this-list == '' ? steps.make-list.outputs.result : workflow.parameters.use-this-list }}"
```

where workflow-level parameter `use-this-list` can be given as a JSON list (e.g., `'["item1","item2"]'`) or an empty string, in which case I'd like the template to use the output of the `make-list` step.

I've tried that conditional expression many different ways -- using different quotations, using `toJson` around different parts of it, etc. -- but argo never seems to be able to understand it.

Is it possible to do something like this? FWIW I haven't found any examples anywhere that attempt this sort of thing.

Comment: Problem of hyphens in the expression templates? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70987499/unable-to-use-jsonpath-function-for-output-parameter-in-argo-workflows/71002847#71002847